# Swift Animation - button with circle behind

Tags: swift, animation, button, swift3, geometry

I'm trying to create de same effect than the app "Music" :

[image]
[image]

When I click on a button, there is a view behind and when the button is not focused anymore, the view is hidden. I do this with TouchUpInside and TouchDown funcs.

```
    @IBAction func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
         self.backgroundMoreView.alpha = 0.0
         self.backgroundMoreView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:
            1.2, y: 1.2)
         sender.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
      }) { (_) in
         self.backgroundMoreView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
         }
   }


   @IBAction func unpressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
         self.backgroundMoreView.alpha = 0.3
         sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y:
            0.8)
      }
   }
```

The problem is that, when I click and hold focus, and then I swipe out of the button, the function unpressed() is not called and the button stay "focused".

I tried also to add `touchUpOutside` function but no result. I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this works (I prefer the exit on leaving the button)

```
@IBAction func touchDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.background.alpha = 1.0
    }) { (_) in
        print("do")
    }
}

@IBAction func touchDragExit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.background.alpha = 0.0
    }) { (_) in
        print("away")
    }
}
```